# Angular2 and webpack, component require sass breaks unit tests

Tags: angular, sass, gulp, webpack, karma-runner

I'm currently starting on a new project using Angular2, Sass, Webpack, writing tests and running them Gulp/Karma. Unfortunately however once I started requiring my Sass files in the components my unit tests broke.  I've seen similar reference to this issue with React & Mocha however I'm not quite sure how to solve it with my setup.

Example:

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: require('./dashboard.component.html'),
    styles: [ require('./dashboard.component.scss') ]
})
export class DashboardComponent {
   ... 
}
```

When I try to run my tests it seems once it tries to load a component requiring a Sass file it breaks.

```
ERROR in ./scripts/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.scss
Module parse failed: [path]/dashboard.component.scss Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
```

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just realized I was missing the sass-loader in my karma.conf.js under the webpack configuration sections.

Just added the following to the loaders:

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'raw-loader!sass-loader' }
```

Now it works fine. whoops!